# Are serotonin levels in humans affected by light?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, circadian-rhythms, neurotransmitter

I'm reading [this Wikipedia article on light therapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_therapy#Light_boxes)  and noticed a peculiar statement:

> The production of the hormone melatonin, a sleep regulator, is
>   inhibited by light and permitted by darkness as registered by
>   photosensitive ganglion cells in the retina. **To some degree, the
>   reverse is true for serotonin**, which has been linked to mood
>   disorders.

If I read this correctly, when melatonin is suppressed, serotonin is released? This makes some sense. **I'm interested if there is any scientific backing to serotonin being affected by light levels.**

Comment: You might want to look into seasonal affective disorder which is possibly related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about humans, but this is true of many vertebrate's retinas. There is [experimental evidence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20504441) showing light-inhibited production of serotonin. This article reviews how serotonin is regulated in response to day lenght (as well as fasting/feeding cycles). The authors suggest a mechanism in which serotonin and ghrelin integrate signals from fasting/feeding and night/day together.

1. [Nowak JZ, Z Urawska E, Zawilska J. Melatonin and its generating system in vertebrate retina: circadian rhythm, effect of environmental lighting and interaction with dopamine. Neurochem Int. 1989;14(4):397-406.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20504441)
2. [Kirsz K, Zieba DA. A review on the effect of the photoperiod and melatonin on interactions between ghrelin and serotonin. Gen Comp Endocrinol. 2012 Nov 1;179(2):248-53. doi: 10.1016/j.ygcen.2012.08.025. Epub 2012 Sep 5.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22974511)

Comment: The second article looks really nice. Is there a place where I can take a look at it for free?

Comment: No, but if you give me your email I can send you a PDF.